# SQL - Copy columns to new table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

Table Post

```
+----+--------+-----------------------+
| id | postId |         path          |
+----+--------+-----------------------+
|  1 |     22 | Hello/World           |
|  2 |     23 | Hello/World/test      |
|  3 |     24 | Hello/World           |
|  4 |     25 | World/Monk            |
|  5 |     26 | Test/Test2            |
|  6 |     27 | Hello/World/test      |
|  7 |     28 | Hello/World/Something |
|  8 |     29 | Hello/World/Noa       |
|  9 |     30 | Hello/World           |
+----+--------+-----------------------+
```

The `id` is the primary key. `postId` is also unique. `path` is not unique. I want a relationship where there is a many-to-one relationship with path and postId. So one postId can have one path, but one path can have many postId's.

Therefor I want to create a new table (Table PostPathMap) that looks like this:

```
+----+--------+
| id | postId |
+----+--------+
| 22 |      1 |
| 23 |      2 |
| 24 |      3 |
| 25 |      4 |
| 26 |      5 |
| 27 |      6 |
| 28 |      7 |
| 29 |      8 |
| 30 |      9 |
+----+--------+
```

where the postId is the primary key. Then I want to delete duplicate entries so my Table Post ends up like :

```
+----+-----------------------+
| id |         path          |
+----+-----------------------+
|  1 | Hello/World           |
|  2 | Hello/World/test      |
|  4 | World/Monk            |
|  5 | Test/Test2            |
|  7 | Hello/World/Something |
|  8 | Hello/World/Noa       |
+----+-----------------------+
```

I therefore need to update PostPathMap. How can I update this table without doing it manually?

Expected PostPathmap after update:

```
+----+--------+
| id | postId |
+----+--------+
| 22 |      1 |
| 23 |      2 |
| 24 |      1 |
| 25 |      4 |
| 26 |      5 |
| 27 |      2 |
| 28 |      7 |
| 29 |      8 |
| 30 |      1 |
+----+--------+
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: I have a hard time following the description of your tables. Can you please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for both tables (including all indexes) and some sample data. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: What about using a view instead of a copy of the table?

Comment: I've edited my post. Hope it is more clear.

Comment: All you need to do is create table for `paths` and have path_id on post, since post only may have one path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the table `PostPathMap` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PostPathMap AS
SELECT postId id, id postId FROM Post;
```

Update `PostPathMap`:

```
UPDATE PostPathMap ppm
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT path, MIN(id) id
  FROM Post
  GROUP BY path
) t ON t.id < ppm.postid
INNER JOIN Post p 
ON p.path = t.path AND p.id = ppm.postid
SET ppm.postid = t.id;
```

and then delete the duplicates from `Post` with a self join in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
DELETE p1 
FROM Post p1 INNER JOIN Post p2
ON p2.path = p1.path AND p2.id < p1.id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=68176b2ef52cb2a92ebdc36af730e0f8).

Comment: But I need to update the `PostPathMap` table once I deleted the duplicates, so the `postId` are pointing to the right `id` in the Post table

Comment: Update to what? Post the expected results for PostPathMap after the update.

Comment: This can't be done after the deletion of the duplicates in Posts. It must be done before.

Comment: Okay. Is there a way to update it before deletion without manually changing one row at a time?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for